# How to output a placeholder image if an Assets field is empty

Tags: templating, assets, conditional

I'm trying to output an Asset image if the Main Image field is populated, and if it's not populated, I'd like to output a placeholder image. But I'm having problems getting the conditional to work - it outputs the image in the Assets field, but when the field is empty, it's not outputting the placeholder image. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
{% if entry.mainImage %}
  {% for asset in entry.mainImage %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130/f5f5f5/ccc.png" height="130" width="130" alt="{{ entry.title }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Try `{% if entry.mainImage|length %}`

Comment: Thanks Brad, that did the job. If you add that as an answer I can mark it as such, otherwise, I'll add it myself tomorrow and steal all your glory (and points). ;-)

Comment: Haha... all yours. I burn my reputation for warmth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Brad for the answer, and the solution was to use `{% if entry.mainImage|length %}` instead of `{% if entry.mainImage %}` for the conditional. So my working code looked like this:

```
{% if entry.mainImage|length %}
  {% for asset in entry.mainImage %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130/f5f5f5/ccc.png" height="130" width="130" alt="{{ entry.title }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Related: here's article on my blog about generating placeholder images uing Twig macro:

[Placeholder image macro for Craft CMS](http://craftsnippets.com/articles/placeholder-image-macro-for-craft-cms?s=s)